# How to type text by cypress cy.type in <ion-input> in Ionic Vue?

Tags: ionic-framework, automated-tests, cypress, ionic-vue

cy.get('[data-cy=insta-comment]').type('hello').should('have.value', 'hello');
cy.get('[data-cy=submitBtn]').click();

```
ion-input data-cy="insta-comment"  
              ion-button data-cy="submitBtn" type="submit"
```

The word hello is not get typed in input feild,
The hello should be typed in input feild,
cypress: 13.6.3,
vite: 5.0.11